# How to increase the acceleration of parent animation in aframe?

Tags: aframe

```
<a-entity class="rota" id="duck1" color="#fdfd96" scale="0.1 0.1 .1" position="2 0 -7" animation="property: rotation; to:0 -360 0; loop:true; easing:linear; dur:30000">
            <a-entity class="rota" color="#F0FFF0" gltf-model="spaceship.glb" animation__mouseenter="property: rotation; to:0 360 0; easing:linear; dur:4000; startEvents: mouseenter" position="20 0 -10"  scale="2 3 3" collison-check="el: #otherduck; radius: 0.15; other-radius: 0.15;"> </a-entity>
        </a-entity>
```

Here are two 'entity': one is parent and another one is child. The animation of parent entity is working properly with `dur:30000`. In child entity I want to reduce the "dur" to `dur:4000`. How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the property of the parent animation using an event-set component on the child.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-event-set-component

```
<a-entity class="rota" color="#F0FFF0" gltf-model="spaceship.glb" 
 event-set__1="_event: mouseenter; _target:#duck1; animation.dur:4000"
 position="20 0 -10"  scale="2 3 3" collison-check="el: #otherduck; radius: 0.15; 
 other-radius: 0.15;"> </a-entity>
```

I'm not sure exactly what the bahaviour of the animation component is when you update the duration on an already-playing animation.

From a quick code-read, it looks like the animation restarts.  Since you have not specified a from position that should mean it just continues from where it had got to.  Hopefully that's what you would want to happen.